# Fontconfig error only appears after pyinstaller execution

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am trying to make a simple python script into an executable to share with non-python users(people who dont know programming). For this I used pysintaller. Before using pysintaller the program(the .py) programm works great. However, the executable produced by pyinstaller gives me the following error:
$Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)

I am kind of new to this error so I tried searching online but I could not find/understand any solution. The weird thing is that when I run the .py file instead of the executable their is no error. This leads to the executable having around a 13 seconds delay between being clicked and the GUI program actually opening.

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre] and how `PyInstaller` is executed.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: `pyinstaller` doesn't compile to real `exe` file (like `C/C++` compilers) but it creates self-extracting `zip` file with extension `exe. When you run it then it needs time to create temporary folder and unzip all files to this folder before it runs your script - so it may need extra time.

Comment: if you use some files with configuration then you have to add it to special file [spec](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html) to inform `pyinstaller` that it has to add this file to `exe`. (Pyinstaller doc: [Using Spec Files](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html)). It may need also use special method to create `/full/path/to/file` - you should find this in documentation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.